# Is it normal that a clock divider made with ring johnson counter has output Undefined if clk starts high?

Tags: vhdl, frequency, counter

[image]I'm making a frequency divider and the easiest way is to use a johnon's counter with D flip flop. The point is that if I make the clk start high, the counter has undefined output, while if I make the clk start low, it all should be ok.

Code of ring johnson's counter ("divide_by is unusued at the moment"):

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity double_period is
    port(
        clk : in std_logic;
        --i 3 bit seguenti rappresentano 8 stati (stato 0 : divisione frequenza per     2, stato 1: divione per 4, stato 3 : divione per 6, etc...)
        divide_by : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
        out_clk : out std_logic
    );
end double_period;

architecture double_period_behaviour of double_period is
signal filoFlottante : std_logic;
component ffd is
    port(
        clk : in std_logic;
        din : in std_logic;
        dout : out std_logic
    );
end component;
signal dInternal : std_logic_vector(8 downto 0);
signal dFirst : std_logic;
begin
dFirst <= not(dInternal(2));
f0 : ffd port map(clk, dFirst, dInternal(0));
f1 : ffd port map(clk, dInternal(0), dInternal(1));
f2 : ffd port map(clk, dInternal(1), dInternal(2));
--f3 : ffd port map(clk, dInternal(2), dInternal(3));
--f4 : ffd port map(clk, dInternal(3), dInternal(4));
--f5 : ffd port map(clk, dInternal(4), dInternal(5));
--f6 : ffd port map(clk, dInternal(5), dInternal(6));
--f7 : ffd port map(clk, dInternal(6), dInternal(7));
--f8 : ffd port map(clk, dInternal(7), dInternal(8));
out_clk <= dInternal(0);
end double_period_behaviour;
```

D FLIP FLOP CODE:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity ffd is
    port(
        clk : in std_logic;
        din : in std_logic;
        dout : out std_logic
    );
end ffd;

architecture ffd_behaviour of ffd is
begin
process(clk)
variable qvar : std_logic := '0';
begin
    if clk'event and clk='1' then
        qvar := din;
    end if;
dout <= qvar;
end process;
end ffd_behaviour;
```

The following is the TESTBENCH:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity double_periodTB is

end double_periodTB;

architecture double_periodTB_behaviour of double_periodTB is
component double_period is
    port(
        clk : in std_logic;

        divide_by : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
        out_clk : out std_logic
    );
end component;
signal clk : std_logic;
signal out_clk : std_logic;
signal divide_by : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
begin
process
begin
clk <= '1'; wait for 10 ns;
clk <= '0'; wait for 10 ns;
end process;
process
begin
divide_by(0) <= '0'; wait for 10 ns;
divide_by(0) <= '0'; wait for 10 ns;
end process;
process
begin
divide_by(1) <= '0'; wait for 10 ns;
divide_by(1) <= '0'; wait for 10 ns;
end process;
process
begin
divide_by(2) <= '0'; wait for 10 ns;
divide_by(2) <= '0'; wait for 10 ns;
end process;
sg : double_period port map(clk, divide_by, out_clk);
end double_periodTB_behaviour;
```

"DIVIDE_BY" IS UNUSUED AT THE MOMENT!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is it normal that a clock divider made with ring johnson counter has output Undefined if clk starts high?**

The short answer is Yes.

You get an event on `clk` assigning an initial value of `'1'`, satisfying the if condition, assigning the value of `din` to `qvar`.

In the case of your three flip flops `f0`, `f1` and `f2` the `din` ports are association with either `dInternal` elements or the `not` expression of `dInternal(2)` using the intermediary signal `dFirst`.

If you were to display delta cycles in your waveform you'd see that the cause of your problem is that the assignment to `dFirst` occurs one delta cycle later.

For those of us who can't display delta cycles we can see that `dFirst` (`not dInternal(2)`) propagated a 'U' into the state of `dbInternal` because of the delta cycle delay:

[image: double_periodtb.png]
*(clickable)*

Once in that `'U'` recirculates.

You can correct the problem by using the rising_edge function found in package std_logic_1164 in your flip flop model:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity ffd is
    port (
        clk:    in  std_logic;
        din:    in  std_logic;
        dout:   out std_logic
    );
end entity ffd;

architecture foo of ffd is
begin
    process (clk)
       variable qvar: std_logic := '0';
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then -- clk'event and clk = '1' then
            qvar := din;
        end if;
        dout <= qvar;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

The `rising_edge` function qualifies it's input with a call to function `TO_01` and uses the `'LAST_VALUE` attribute to determine there's actually a rising edge which means it won't trigger erroneously:

```
    FUNCTION rising_edge  (SIGNAL s : std_ulogic) RETURN BOOLEAN IS
    BEGIN
        RETURN (s'EVENT AND (To_X01(s) = '1') AND
                            (To_X01(s'LAST_VALUE) = '0'));
    END;
```

This gives:

[image: double_periodtb_fixed_ff.png]
*(clickable)*

Just in case you were ever wondering why the rising_edge and falling_edge functions were included in package std_logic_1164, now you have a concrete example.